# Index error in the uniqueness of two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created to tables:

```
class CreateWines < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :wines do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :producer

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateWineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :wine_items do |t|
      t.references :wine, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :vintage

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :wine_items, [:wine, :vintage], unique: true
  end
end
```

Adding the index for te uniqueness of two columns.
In the `WineItem` model I added the validation:

```
validates :wine, uniqueness: {scope: :vintage}
```

I can insert a `WineItem`

```
WineItem.create(wine_id: 1, vintage: "2018")
```

but if I try another `Wine` with the same `vintage` an Unique constraint failed:

```
WineItem.create(wine_id: 2, vintage: "2018")
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed:
 index 'index_wine_items_on_wine_and_vintage')
```

I only want not to insert same wines with same vintage, and all the references tell me this is the way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just out of courisity - why is vintage a string and not an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `uniqueness` is the helper validates that the `attribute's value` is unique, so your validation should be

```rb
validates :wine_id, uniqueness: {scope: :vintage}
```

Comment: Yes and the index should be `add_index :wine_items, [:wine_id, :vintage], unique: true`